# How do you define an array of different examples in a Swagger spec?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I'm trying to document an API with a static swagger file that can return some JSON that contains an array that looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "type": "type A",
    "field A": "this field is specific to type A"
  },
  {
    "type": "type B",
    "field B": "this field is specific to type B"
  }
]
```

I've tried a few different ways of defining my spec using either polymorphism or explicitly defining multiple examples. The examples have always either ended up looking like:

```
[
  {
    "type": "type A",
    "field A": "this field is specific to type A",
    "field B": "this field is specific to type B"
  }
]
```

or just:

```
[
  {
    "type": "type A",
    "field A": "this field is specific to type A"
  }
]
```

Is there a way to define an example in my swagger spec so that the example payload shown by swagger-ui will contain an array containing an example of Type A and an example of Type B like the first JSON I wrote?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a swagger schema that includes an array of varying types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318849/how-do-you-create-a-swagger-schema-that-includes-an-array-of-varying-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

You can only define one example per mime-type per response :

```
{
  "description": "A response",
  "schema": {
    "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "examples": {
    "application/json": {
      "name": "Dog"
    },
    "application/xml": {
      "name": "Cat"
    }
  }
}
```

If you want add complete scenario, I suggest you to write (or generate) a full scenario example in an HTML page and link it with an [externalDocs](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#external-documentation-object). You can define externalDocs in root, operations, tags and schemas.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you can. In the responses object, put an examples object with an array as the value of the mime type. like so:

```
    400:
      description: Bad Request
      examples:
        application/json:
          [
            {
              code:10000,
              message:"Missing Input Parameters",
              fieldA: "AAAAA"
            },{
              code:42,
              message:"Ask the question",
              fieldB: "BBBBBB"
            }
          ]
    default:
      description: Unexpected error
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
```