# Swagger array of different objects

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, json-api

For example I need to represent following structure in swagger yaml format:

```
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "people",
      "id": "42",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "John",
        "age": 80,
        "gender": "male"
      }
    }
  ]
```

With single object everything is fine:

```
  included:
    type: "array"
    items:
      type: object
      properties:
        type:
          type: "string"
        # and so on
```

The question is what if I need to describe something like:

```
"included": [{
    "type": "people",
    "id": "9",
    "attributes": {
      "first-name": "Dan",
      "last-name": "Gebhardt",
      "twitter": "dgeb"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/people/9"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "comments",
    "id": "5",
    "attributes": {
      "body": "First!"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "data": { "type": "people", "id": "2" }
      }
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/comments/5"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "comments",
    "id": "12",
    "attributes": {
      "body": "I like XML better"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "data": { "type": "people", "id": "9" }
      }
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/comments/12"
    }
  }]
```

I know that in OpenAPI it's possible ( aka swagger 3 ) and tried some workarounds in current version but with no luck.

Comment: In your 2nd example both array items have same-type properties, so it's essentially the same as the 1st example with 1 array item. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hi @Helen thanks for noticing. I've updated second object. Orginaly these objects wouldn't be the same. They will have different attributes, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a swagger schema that includes an array of varying types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318849/how-do-you-create-a-swagger-schema-that-includes-an-array-of-varying-types)